# phonegap failed clean or build iOS with error 65

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap

Im working on a `Phonegap` project. the app works fine on android. now im attempting to build the ios version. however after adding the ios platform using `phonegap platform add ios`. i cannot clean or build the app as it keeps giving the error 65. here is in detail:

**paltform Version:**

`node --version v6.10.3
phonegap --version 6.5.0
cordova --version 6.5.0`

**phonegap plugins list:**

```
com.dooble.audiotoggle 1.0.0 "AudioToggle"
com.dooble.phonertc 2.1.0 "PhoneRTC"
com.hiraqui.ringtone 0.6.1 "Ringtone"
com.lampa.startapp 0.1.4 "startApp"
cordova-plugin-android-permissions 0.10.0 "Permissions"
cordova-plugin-android-support-v4 21.0.1 "Android Support v4"
cordova-plugin-app-event 1.2.0 "Application Events"
cordova-plugin-audioinput 0.3.0 "Audio Input"
cordova-plugin-camera 2.3.1 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-camera-preview 0.9.0 "cordova-plugin-camera-preview"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.1.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.5 "Console"
cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview 2.3.0 "Crosswalk WebView Engine"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.6 "Device"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 1.3.1 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-facebook4 1.7.4 "Facebook Connect"
cordova-plugin-file 4.3.1 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.6.1 "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-googleplus 5.1.1 "Google SignIn"
cordova-plugin-headsetdetection 3.0.0 "Headset Detection"
cordova-plugin-media 3.0.1-dev "Media"
cordova-plugin-network-information 1.3.2 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 1.0.1 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.2 "Whitelist"
de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification 0.8.4 "LocalNotification"
```

**ERRORS:**

if i **clean** the project after adding ios platform:

```
=== CLEAN TARGET MM OF PROJECT MM WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
Check dependencies
warning: no rule to process file '/Users/poorya/bb/app/platforms/ios/mm/Plugins/cordova-plugin-audioinput/AudioReceiver.h' of type sourcecode.c.h for architecture armv7
“Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION) is required to be configured correctly for targets which use Swift. Use the [Edit > Convert > To Current Swift Syntax…] menu to choose a Swift version or use the Build Settings editor to configure the build setting directly.
** CLEAN FAILED **
The following build commands failed:
    Check dependencies
(1 failure)
Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -project,MM.xcodeproj,-configuration,Debug,-alltargets,clean
```

this also happens if i want to build the project, however with more errors

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I`m having the same issue. :(

Comment: @BrianMoreno this seems to happen in OSx and since the phonertc needs to be setup in Xcode. the solution for me was to build it with xcode(as many suggest on github). 
you need to open plaltforms/ios/{projectname}.xcodeproj with xcode

Comment: @BrianMoreno here is a good post on how to use xcode 7 and 8 together http://radex.io/xcode7-xcode8/

Comment: Thanks, I'll read up on it! :)